# Including "dummy" -columns in table doubles the total query time

Tags: sql, sql-server

my first post at the forums! Have found a lot of good stuff here over the years however.

Im having some performance trouble in a MSSQL view.

To SELECT * FROM wi1_updates takes about 11 seconds, with about 69000 rows.
The view consists of some LEFT JOINs, some CASEs and 74 "dummy" columns needed to match the look of another table. I tried to remove all dummy-columns from the table, and the total time is reduced to about 5 seconds, versus 11 seconds with all columns selected. To somehow optimize the dummy-columns seems like a way forward.

All dummy columns look like this in the SELECT statement:
,0.00 as amount_p
,0.00 as amount_ytd
,0.00 as amount_pyytd
,0.00 as amount_py

I noticed that if I replace 0.00 with 0, the time is reduced by about 2 seconds. But I wonder if the gurus at stackoverflow got some other tricks up their sleeve? To simply remove all dummy-colums is not possible since the view must match a datawarehouse table used by an application.

Thx!

Comment: Try setting the packet size in your connection string to the maximum permitted (`Packet Size=32767` if you're using a .NET connection string). For very wide rows, reducing packet overhead can have a significant effect. Make sure to measure processing time "correctly", however -- SSMS is a poor benchmark as it has significant overhead in rendering. Measure with your actual application.

Comment: This is really too specific for your particular case to answer.  The base optimization rules would be make sure you have indexes created (if needed),  Look at the actual execution plan and see what is eating the time up.

Comment: Thx for your replies.

About the connection string - I guess the packet size is important when using the application? In my case I do the testing in SQL Manager. I want to optimize the query first.

The tables got indexes already. These might be improved, but since removing the dummy-columns almost improves the query performance by more than 50 % I think thats the right place to start, if possible.

Comment: Have you tried using nulls instead of 0 or 0.00 on your dummy columns ?.

Comment: If you want to to optimize the query and measure both execution and transmission overhead "fairly", use `bcp` -- `bcp "select ..." queryout nul -n` will use native data types and throw away the results, which is a relatively pure measurement of execution plus transmission time (fairer than SSMS, at least). (Since `bcp` still writes to the console, you can eliminate even that with PowerShell: `(measure-command { bcp ... }).TotalSeconds`.) To set the packet size in `bcp`, use the `-a` parameter.

Comment: If you're stuck with only SSMS, you should at least measure time using the "results to text" option, and you can improve on that by checking "discard results after execution" option (Tools -> Options -> Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Text -> Discard results after the query executes). This eliminates the overhead for rendering the result set as a grid, which can be considerable for a big result set. To get only the execution time on the server without *any* client overhead, use a `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` statement and check the "messages" tab for details.